# Connect Galaxy Watch4 with Andorid Studio on Windows 10

Tags: samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I have developed an app for WearOs and I want to test it on a galax Watch4 but I can not connect it to my PC. I mean android studio does not recognize that my device is connected via USB to the pc. Someone with the same issue?
How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy Watch 4 doesn't support USB debugging. Connect to a wifi, activate wifi debugging, connect with adb to the ip adress of your watch:

in my case:
adb connect 192.168.0.110:5555

Answer (score 0):

if you update to wear os 4 you need to pair your pc. enable remote debugging on the watch, enter adb pair {IP-Adress}:{port} {paircode}

after that if you enable remote debugging it will connect to the pc automatically (well most of the time)